# Problemas con fetch en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Necesito tomar las frases generadas en mi script de javascript lo cual ya logré, ahora la cosa es enviarla usando fecth hacia un archivo php desde mi código de javascript para enviarlo a mi base de datos local, pero no logro imprimirlo y en la consola me marcan el error de abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
fetch('http://localhost/xampp/subir_datos.php',{
        method:'POST',
        body:'datos'
    })
    .then(res=>res.json()
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
    }));
```

Y este es mi código php

```
$frase=$_POST['frase'];
echo json_encode('Esta es la frase desde el archivo php'.$frase);
```

ayuda por favor me queda poco tiempo para entregar esta práctica :c

Comment: Eso se lo quite antes de tomar la captura porque si lo dejo como estaba me dice 

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Comment: Si estás obteniendo un `404` significa que el archivo `subir_datos.php` no está en esa URL.

Comment: Tengo ambos archivos en la misma carpeta

Comment: ¿Verificaste que lo subiste? ¿Por casualidad no usaste mayúsculas? ¿Que pasa si le apuntas directamente?

Comment: El nombre esta bien y ambos estan en el mismo directorio

Comment: ¿Que ves si entras directo a `/subir_datos.php`?

Comment: nada, porque debe recibir lo que envíe desde javascript, ademas que la consola me marca que el fetch está mal declarado

Comment: @Juan A ver, si cambias ese `echo json_encode` por un `echo "hola mundo";` e intentas abrir directamente la url `https://phrases-random-generator-js.netlify.app/subir_datos.php` que ocurre?

Comment: @Juan, cuando entro a esa [`URL`](https://phrases-random-generator-js.netlify.app/subir_datos.php) yo [veo esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLbe2.png). Básicamente dice que el archivo no existe

Comment: Me imprime el hola mundo

Comment: ahorita lo que hago es webscraping en esa pagina, y solo obtengo el h1 donde está la frase y quiero tomar esa frase y enviarla a mi servidor local, pero para eso quiero usar fetch para pasarla a php y desde ahí enviarlo a mi base de datos local, ejecuto mi script como extensión en esa página y miro los resultados el la consola del navegador

Comment: Tal como ahora lo has contado quizás lo que necesitas es cambiar esto: `fetch('subir_datos.php'` por esto: `fetch('http://localhost/subir_datos.php'`

Comment: Pero me piden que tenga ambos archivos en la misma carpeta fuera de xampp y debe ser una extensión

Comment: Gente, esto debería ir al [chat].

Comment: El resultado debe ser una extensión para chrome que contenga esos 2 archivos

Comment: No le veo el sentido a incluir el subir_datos.php a una extensión para chrome cuando este no puede ejecutarlo directamente, sino a traves de algun servidor que soporte PHP, por eso decia lo del localhost.  No se exactamente el enunciado de tu tarea, pero creo que no van por ahí los tiros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se porque debe  utilizas `json_encode()`  con un `string` pero si cambias el código de esta manera funcionara correctamente

PHP

```
$frase=$_POST['frase'];
echo 'Esta es la frase desde el archivo php'.$frase;
die();
```

JavaScript

```
fetch('http://localhost/xampp/subir_datos.php',{
   method:'POST',
   body:'datos'
})
.then(res=>res.text())
.then(data=>{
    console.log(data)
});
```